# RegEx a substring in a specific combo

Tags: regex

Say i have a string as follows

> ' *my test string  1 111:222:444: &**EVERYTHING INSIDE THIS REGARLESS OF CHAR OR INT**£ This is a test string (123456789)'

I want to return every thing inside `&` and the `£` sign or match it.

Any body could help me with the `regex` expression for this.

Comment: have a particular language in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible for there to be multiple £ characters in the string? If so, you need to be careful about greediness. Mark's pattern will not stop on the first £ but rather the last £ in the string. You may want a more restricted pattern, like

```
/&([^£]*)£/
```

That pattern will stop on the first £ after the & in your string. It also uses a captured group so you can extract just the text you want. There is one other thing to note here, which is if there's multiple &'s before the £, this will start capturing at the first &. If you want to capture at the latest & before the £ you may want this pattern instead:

```
/&([^£&]*)£/
```

Answer (score 2):

You might have to be careful of character encodings, but apart from that the following should work:

```
 /&.*?£/
```

Edit: Updated to stop on the first `£`.